# How to split a FASTA file imported as data.frame through ">"

Tags: r, dataframe, fasta

I fave imported a FASTA file in R to a single-column data frame that looks like this:

```
dna.sequences <- data.frame(c(">ID1", "sequence1", ">ID2" , "sequence2", ...))
```

I want to split this data frame in two columns, and eliminate the '>' before every ID so I finally get something like this

```
    new_dna <- data.frame(
          ID = c("ID1", "ID2" ... ),
            sequence = c("sequence1", "sequence2" ... )              
            )
```

Thanks in advance, Jose

Comment: *How* did you import the file? As you’ve noticed this isn’t a particularly helpful representation, which is why none of the usual libraries (e.g. [‘seqinr’](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/seqinr/versions/3.6-1/topics/read.fasta)) import FASTA like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your file is like this:

```
writeLines(">ID1\nGAGA\n>ID2\nTATA","test.fa")
dna.sequences = read.table("test.fa")

dna.sequences
    V1
1 >ID1
2 GAGA
3 >ID2
4 TATA
```

Assuming it's read correctly:

```
rows = 1:nrow(dna.sequences)
data.frame(ID = gsub(">","",as.character(dna.sequences[rows %% 2==1,1])),
sequences = dna.sequences[rows %% 2==0,1])
```

Or much better, read it in directly using a package meant for this:

```
library(Biostrings)
data = readDNAStringSet("test.fa")

data
  A DNAStringSet instance of length 2
    width seq                                               names               
[1]     4 GAGA                                              ID1
[2]     4 TATA                                              ID2

dna.sequences = data.frame(ID=names(data),sequences=as.character(data))

dna.sequences
     ID sequences
ID1 ID1      GAGA
ID2 ID2      TATA
```

Comment: glad it was useful!

Answer (score 2):

Using ‘seqinr’:

```
seqs = read.fasta('filename', as.string = TRUE)
dna_sequences = data.frame(ID = names(seqs), sequence = seqs)
```

And using the ‘magrittr’ pipe we can do away with the temporary variable:

```
dna_sequences = read.fasta('filename', as.string = TRUE) %>%
    {data.frame(ID = names(.), sequence = .)}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you always have alternate `ID` and `sequence` values you can use vector recycling technique.

```
transform(data.frame(ID = dna.sequences$col[c(TRUE, FALSE)], 
                     sequence = dna.sequences$col[c(FALSE, TRUE)]), 
          ID = sub('^>', '', ID))

#   ID  sequence
#1 ID1 sequence1
#2 ID2 sequence2
```

**data**

```
dna.sequences <- data.frame(col = c(">ID1", "sequence1", ">ID2" , "sequence2"))
```

Comment: This works but it should be unnecessary when importing the data correctly.